# bootstrap change size and font of text in legend tag

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, legend

I wonder if it's possible to change the size and font of the legend inside a well.

```
<legend>Title</legend>
```

When i try to add a heading tag i get error. Is there any way to do what this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

## Option 1:

This seems to be working for me and this is the optimal way:

```
<legend><h4> Hello</h4> </legend>
```

Example: http://www.bootply.com/116594

---

### Option 2

Or just change the actual CSS file that contains `legend`:

```
legend{
 font-size: 6px; 
}
```

Example: http://www.bootply.com/116589

---

#### Option 3

Another way to do this would just be doing the following but it's best to avoid inline CSS:

```
 <legend style="font-size:32px"> Hello </legend>
```

Example: http://www.bootply.com/116593

Comment: adding h4 like Option1 makes the text jump outside of the well, very strange. However the Option3 did it for me, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

2022 answer:
In Bootstrap version 4.x.x You can use display headings as:

```
<legend class="display-1">Title</legend>
```

or:

```
<legend class="h1">Title</legend>
```

You can also use another solutions for version 5 and above:

```
<legend class="fs-1">Title</legend>
```

It helps to keep the semantics over the document and can be customized if necessary.

Sources:

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/content/typography/#headings

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.6/content/typography/#display-headings